# maintaining a sorted jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, accordion

I have a situation where I receive certain events over time that each have a timestamp associated with them. I am putting it into a Jquery accordion section that is labelled by date. It works except that I wish to maintain the accordion sections in sorted descending order, i.e most recent date at the top and events belonging to that date go into that section. Here is the complete code I have so far, currently I just append a new date to the end. How do I insert so that it is sorted?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
});

function getRandInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))
}

function getRandomTime() {
  var t = ['AM', 'PM']
  var hr = getRandInt(13);
  var mn = getRandInt(60);
  var sec = getRandInt(60);
  var ampm = t[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]
  return (hr + ':' + mn + ':' + sec + " " + ampm);
}

function getRandomDate() {

  var month = getRandInt(13);
  var day = getRandInt(28);
  return ('2018-' + month + '-' + day);
}

function getRandomEvent() {
  var events = ['General Event', 'Random', 'Splash', 'Car crash', 'Touchdown', 'Rain', 'Snow'];
  var rand = events[Math.floor(Math.random() * events.length)];
  return rand;
}

function getRandomSection(sections) {
  var rand = sections[Math.floor(Math.random() * sections.length)];
  return rand;
}

function getPopupDivId(t, e, d) {
  var popup_div_str = t + e;
  var popup_div_id = popup_div_str.replace(/\s{1,}/g, "");
  popup_div_id = popup_div_id.replace(/:/g, "");
  return popup_div_id;
}

function getDescriptiveDate(dateStr) {
  var d_t = dateStr.split("T");
  var timeStr = d_t[0] + " " + d_t[1];
  console.log(timeStr);
  var date = new Date(timeStr + ' UTC');
  return "Event time: " + date.toString()
}

function makeTable(eventDetails) {
  var d = getDescriptiveDate("2018-11-07T00:49:05");

  var popupStr = d + '<br>' + '<table border="1"><tr><th>Parameter Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>';
  var data = JSON.parse(eventDetails);
  var startTag = '<tr><td>';
  var endTag = '</td>';
  var rowEnd = '</tr>'

  for (var key in data) {
    popupStr += (startTag + key + endTag + '<td>' + data[key] + endTag + rowEnd);
  }
  return popupStr + '</table>';

}
var currentDialog = '';

function setPopupDiv(t, e, d, popup_div_id) {
  var table = makeTable('{"Temp": 24, "WindChill": "14", "Dew point": 10}');
  var popup_div = '<div id="dialog' + popup_div_id + '\" ' + 'style="display:none">' + table + '</div>';

  console.log("setPopupDiv: popup div: " + popup_div);
  $('.' + d).append(popup_div);

  $('#' + popup_div_id).click(function() {
    $(function() {
      if (currentDialog == '') {
        currentDialog = "#dialog" + popup_div_id;
      } else {
        console.log('closing dialog' + currentDialog);
        $(currentDialog).dialog('close');
        currentDialog = "#dialog" + popup_div_id;
      }
      $("#dialog" + popup_div_id).dialog();
      $("#dialog" + popup_div_id).dialog('open');
    });
    console.log("dialog link click");

    return false;
  });
}

/* "Create new accordion" button handler */
function addData() {
  var d = getRandomDate();
  var e = getRandomEvent();
  var t = getRandomTime();
  var popup_div_id = getPopupDivId(t, e, d);
  var ev = '<a href="" id=\"' + popup_div_id + '\">' + t + ' ' + '</a>' + e;
  var section = '<h3>' + d + '</h3>';
  var dom_element = section + '<div>' + '<ul class=\"' + d + '\">' + '<li>' + ev + '</li></ul>' + '</div>';
  $('#accordion').append(dom_element)
    .accordion('destroy').accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  setPopupDiv(t, e, d, popup_div_id);
  console.log("addData(): " + dom_element);
  var e2 = getRandomEvent();
  var t2 = getRandomTime();
  popup_div_id = getPopupDivId(t2, e2, d);

  var ev2 = '<li>' + '<a href="" id=\"' + popup_div_id + '\">' + t2 + ' ' + '</a>' + e2 + '</li>';
  $('.' + d).append(ev2);
  setPopupDiv(t2, e2, d, popup_div_id);

}

function addDataActual(eventDate, eventTime, eventType) {
  var popup_div_id = getPopupDivId(eventTime, eventType, eventDate);
  var evt = '<a href="" id=\"' + popup_div_id + '\">' + eventTime + ' ' + '</a>' + eventType;
  var section = '<h3>' + eventDate + '</h3>';
  var dom_element = section + '<div>' + '<ul class=\"' + eventDate + '\">' + '<li>' + evt + '</li></ul>' + '</div>';

  var arrayOfClassNames = $("#accordion *").map(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class')) {
      if ($(this)[0].nodeName == 'UL') {
        if (this.className == eventDate) {
          return this.className;
        }
      }
    }
  }).get();
  if (arrayOfClassNames.length == 0) {

    /* New section */

    $('#accordion').append(dom_element)
      .accordion('destroy').accordion({
        collapsible: true
      });
    setPopupDiv(eventTime, eventType, eventDate, popup_div_id);
    console.log(dom_element);
  } else {
    /* Exists already*/
    d = arrayOfClassNames[0];
    popup_div_id = getPopupDivId(eventTime, eventType, d);

    var eventToAppend = '<li>' + '<a href="" id=\"' + popup_div_id + '\">' + eventTime + ' ' + '</a>' + eventType + '</li>';
    $('.' + d).append(eventToAppend);
    setPopupDiv(eventTime, eventType, d, popup_div_id);
  }

}

function addDataOrNew() {
  var arrayOfClassNames = $("#accordion *").map(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class')) {
      if ($(this)[0].nodeName == 'UL') {
        return this.className;
      }
    }
  }).get();

  var toss = getRandInt(2);
  if (toss == 0) {

    var d = getRandomSection(arrayOfClassNames);
    console.log("toss returned 0, adding to existing section " + d);
    console.log("Chosen one to add to:" + d);
    var e = getRandomEvent();
    var t = getRandomTime();
    addDataActual(d, t, e);
  } else {

    var d = getRandomDate();
    console.log("toss returned 1, adding a new section " + d);
    var e = getRandomEvent();
    var t = getRandomTime();
    addDataActual(d, t, e);
  }
}

function addDataToRandomSection() {
  var e = getRandomEvent();
  var t = getRandomTime();

  var arrayOfClassNames = $("#accordion *").map(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class')) {
      if ($(this)[0].nodeName == 'UL') {
        return this.className;
      }
    }
  }).get();
  console.log(arrayOfClassNames);
  d = getRandomSection(arrayOfClassNames);
  console.log("Chosen one:" + d);
  var e2 = getRandomEvent();
  var t2 = getRandomTime();
  var popup_div_id = getPopupDivId(t2, e2, d);

  var ev2 = '<li>' + '<a href="" id=\"' + popup_div_id + '\">' + t2 + ' ' + '</a>' + e2 + '</li>'
  $('.' + d).append(ev2);
  setPopupDiv(t2, e2, d, popup_div_id);
}

function addDataToTopSection() {
  var e2 = getRandomEvent();
  var t2 = getRandomTime();

  var arrayOfClassNames = $("#accordion *").map(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class')) {
      if ($(this)[0].nodeName == 'UL') {
        return this.className;
      }
    }
  }).get();
  d = arrayOfClassNames[0];
  var popup_div_id = getPopupDivId(t2, e2, d);
  setPopupDiv(t2, e2, d, popup_div_id);
  var ev2 = '<li>' + '<a href="" id=\"' + popup_div_id + '\">' + t2 + ' ' + '</a>' + e2 + '</li>'
  $('.' + d).append(ev2);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<!doctype html>

<button onclick="addData()" class="regular">Create new Accordion</button>
<button onclick="addDataToRandomSection()" class="regular">Add data to random section</button>
<button onclick="addDataOrNew()" class="regular">Add new section or append to existing</button>
<fieldset id="patient-event-list">
  <legend>Event History</legend>
  <div id="eventinfo-body">
    <button type="button" id="more" onclick="addDataToTopSection()">More history</button>
  </div>
  <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Sorted by what...?If it's 'by date' you have half the answer, however, any order/filter by will bring you more trouble and work. I'ld suggest to use VueJS or AngularJS to help you with this.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to append to the beginning (i.e prepend?), I think even that is something that I can work with for my particular problem. Currently I am just appending to the end.

Comment: Then it would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: Instead of append, use prepend; You're probably blocked because it's too much code there and that code is/will touch with the next... Be careful